# Django runserver with DEBUG True serving the wrong static files

Tags: django, django-staticfiles, django-channels, django-1.10

Trying to server staticfiles via runserver for development, with Django 1.10

I have `'django.contrib.staticfiles'` in my `INSTALLED_APPS` and the following relevant settings:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder",
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    path('node_modules'),  # resolves to `node_modules/` in the project root
]
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = path('static')  # resolves to `path/` in the project root
```

This works fine for collectstatic, and serves fine via NginX directly.

However with runserver + `DEBUG=True`, I'm expecting Django webserver to serve from the `static/` folder, but instead it is serving from `node_modules/` folder.

If I remove/rename `node_modules/` then I get 404s for static files.

The static files are collected by copy (not symlink).

I'm using Django channels which could be hijacking everything as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what the staticfiles app does: it wraps the built-in runserver command to serve static files directly from the source directories, so that there is no need to run collectstatic in development.

**Edit** You could disable the automatic handling by running runserver with the [`--nostatic`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#cmdoption-runserver--nostatic) flag, and point the [static URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development) at your STATIC_ROOT manually:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += [
        static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    ]
```

Comment: Bingo! Thanks. Although `static()` returns a list itself so no need to wrap it in `[ ]` lest you incur `?: (urls.E004) Your URL pattern [<RegexURLPattern None ^static\/(?P<path>.*)$>] is invalid. Ensure that urlpatterns is a list of url() instances.`